# Spring Boot add header in forthcoming response by exception or AOP

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, aop

How can I add a header in the response to avoid interrupting normal service process? This operation I want to add in *OncePerRequestFilter* and maybe add header by AOP or Exception. Because this will not affect a lot to my original code.

My question:

If the token is expired, which is in the header of request? I want refresh the token and add the new token into the header of response. This operation will not affect normal service logic, which means it also has a normal body by *controller*.

```
Assess-Token: "xxx"
Connection: Keep-Alive

{
// normal serivce response in body
}
```

Now, I could only response the new refreshed token in body. This operation will be interrupted for all service in this request. Which like this:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive

{
Assess-Token: "xxx" // normal service has been interrupted, only token
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as far as I understood you want the following - in case if incoming Access Token is expired, you want to reissue it and ship it back to the client, but the body of the response must not be affected. If this is the case, let me help, but first: your request must contain a refresh token along with access token. Well, you can, just technically, reissue an access token if it is expired without refresh token check, but this is obviously **really, really insecure**. This is just a note :)

So, in regard to java servlet API, why not to use simple **HttpServletResponse#setHeader()**? Or the other option is to take advantage
of Spring **ResponseEntity** class. For example:

```
    @PostMapping
    public void apiMethod(@RequestBody LegalEntity legalEntity, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // TODO: 10.09.2021 ship refresh token along with access token
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer ...");
    }
```

or for example this:

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> apiMethod(@RequestBody LegalEntity legalEntity, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // TODO: 10.09.2021 ship refresh token along with access token
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer ..").build();
    }
```

Another scenario is if you want extract this logic from your controller resource completely. Well, this technically can be achieved by the means of [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html).

**Still** from my perspective, it will be great to perform all operations, related to your token (reissue, validate or whatever) before it reaches the DispatcherServlet, I mean, within a [FilterChain](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/FilterChain.html).

For example, it you are looking in the way to check is passed token valid and if it is expired, then trying to reissue new one - extract it into new **Filter**. More specifically, Spring Security has couple of predefined abstractions out there, for example [OncePerRequestFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html). This is just my opinion.

As you can see, there is a lot of options out there. The final choice depends on what exactly you want. Hope I have given you some direction to further investigation, have a nice day!

Comment: Very thank you, your answer is very clear and complete.

Answer (score 0):

Very thank @misha2048, his answer is very clear and complete, which hint me.

Here I copy my implemention, for anyone seek for the answer

```java
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            // validation the token
        } catch (RefreshTokenException e) {
            response.addHeader("accessToken", e.getToken());
            log.info("Refresh Token");
        } catch (TokenException e) {
            // deal token expired
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```